# Database Design 101: How to link two columns

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-design, constraints

I am trying to setup a phone list for my company in MSSQL 2005.

The current schema I have works, but I would like to add a Column in the Employee Table named "EmployeeCompany" and have it pull from the "CompanyName" column in the Department.

How would I link those two columns if the CompanyName in Department table is not a PK?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank You,
CJ

[image: Database Design Example]

Comment: Why not link to department_id?

Comment: DB design 101: do not do that. Also, when you have a FK to something,  that something has to be unique, PK or AK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know employee's department, and you know department's company, then you also know employee's company. You can express this as a simple JOIN in the SQL and you can even "hide" this JOIN behind a VIEW if you wish to simplify the client code.

As a general rule: **data that can be inferred shouldn't be stored**, unless you are trying to solve a specific performance problem.

Let me break-down this line of thinking:

- If a piece of data can be **inferred** from the data you already have in the database,
- then trying to store it in the database is **redundant**
- and unnecessarily takes **storage space**
- and can lead to **data inconsistencies**<sup>1</sup>
- and therefore **shouldn't be physically stored** in the database,
- unless there is a **specific, measurable performance problem** you are trying solve by caching the redundant data, that is serious enough<sup>2</sup> to justify the danger of data inconsistencies.

There is, however, a way to have both redundancy and integrity by "abusing" the fact that referential integrity *migrates* attributes. The "Case 2" of [Damir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15417061/533120) explins one way, let me offer another:

[image]

As you can see, a foreign key (`FKx` in the diagram above) doesn't have to reference a primary key - it can can also reference an alternate key (`Ux`). This allows you to keep `Company_id` and `Department_id` as primary keys of their respective tables and avoid disturbing the rest of the model<sup>3</sup>.

---

*<sup>1</sup> If there are two pieces of data describing the same thing, and one of them is updated, there is a always danger you could forget (say, due to an application bug) to update the other. Unless you can coax the DBMS itself to do it for you, as explained lower in the answer.*

*<sup>2</sup> Such as excessive JOINs or expensive aggregations.*

*<sup>3</sup> I.e. other tables that may reference company or department.*

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

In The Department Table, you store the `company_id`, which is a key, not the `company name`.

When you want to query-out an employee's company, you do it like this:

```
SELECT
   LastName,
   FirstName,
   CompanyName
FROM
   Employee
   INNER JOIN Department ON employee.department_id = department.department_id
   INNER JOIN Company ON department.company_id = company.company_id
```

Comment: I understand how to select it via query. But isn't there a way to reference the Company ID inside the Employee Table?

Comment: Yes -- if that's specifically what you want, then add a company_id field.  But as for whether or not that's a good idea, consider the discrepancy that could open-up down the road, where you remember to update the company in the department table, but forget to update it in the employee table; just depending on how you wrote the query, you'd end up with different companies for the same employee and not be able to tell which one was correct.

Answer (score 1):

Case 1 -- using IDs

[image]

---

Case 2 -- Natural, composite keys

[image]

Comment: The problem with this is you can still add a user who's Company ID is X and Depart is Y, when Dept Y does not go in Company X.

Comment: I can just insert a record for a new employee straight into the table.

Comment: @CryptoJones -- please try and post the code which managed to do that.

Comment: @CryptoJones; sorry, some kind of error there, can not see the link.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a third table called Company which has two columns - CompanyId (the primary key) and CompanyName. I would then use CompanyId as the foreign key in Department and then DepartmentId as the foreign key in Employee.

Comment: There are three tables in my example.